# could not add bounty of 50 to question of other

Tags: support, bounty

I wanted to add a bounty of 50 points to 
[How to construct three mutually orthogonal circles in stereographic projection?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637449/how-to-construct-three-mutually-orthogonal-circles-in-stereographic-projection)

Some details:

- The question is not my own
- I did answer this question but later realised my answer is incomplete.

But somehow I was only able to add a bounty of 100 points or more.

Why is this, or did I make a mistake somewhere in the making of this bounty?

Also if I somehow manage to make the construction before the bounty expires can I or the questioner award the bounty back to me?

PS no need to change the bounty to 50 points only, I just wanted to give some attention to this undocumented  behavior

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Re: i just wanted to give some attention to this undocumented behavior)

From https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty:

> To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).

P.S.

(Re: Also if I somehow manage to make the construction before the bounty expires can I or the questioner award the bounty back to me?)

No. From the same page:

> All bounties are (...) non-refundable under any circumstances.

Comment: Thanks overlooked that, but i don't want to refund the bounty to me  i just want to give it to writer of the right answer

Comment: @Willemien: A bounty can never be awarded to the user who offered it.  ([MSO bounty faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/214632).)